# Show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z ∈V$ for a holomorphic and continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $V=D(0,1)$ is the unit disk. Suppose that $f ∈ C(\overline V)  ∩ H(V)$ i.e. $f$ is continuous on $\overline V$ and $f\restriction_V$ is holomorphic on $V$, $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z  ∈ \overline V.$   Show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z  ∈V$

I am a bit unsure about how to do this because I think this is similar to Schwarz Lemma but I tried to use Cauchy Integral formula:
$|f(z_0)| = |\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{D(0,1-\epsilon)} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} dz |$ to find a way to bound the integral. However, I could not get anywhere, so a little help would be great about how to approach this problem correctly.

Comment: That *is* the Schwarz Lemma: You have $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in D(0, 1)$.

Comment: Continuity on the boundary is not required.

Comment: Please clarify why you think that the Schwarz Lemma can not be applied.

Comment: @MartinR because here $f$ is continuous on $\overline V$ and $f\restriction_V$ is holomorphic on $V$, $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z  ∈ \overline V.$ In Schwarz Lemma f is holomorphic on V and the conditions are for all $z ∈V$ not $z  ∈ \overline V.$

Comment: @esquire: That means that you have *stronger* conditions on $f$.